# JSONP via getJson not working?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I have getJson like this:

```
 $.getJSON(userUrl+'scanp?callback=?', { 'someparametar': 100 }, function(data){  
  console.log(data);
});
```

and I do get a response from my url, and it looks like this:

```
'"jQuery1110010384737118147314_1401820556204({'hasWon':'false','code':'120580e9fce67a4921f31af7ffa358cc10c83b10','defaultReward':'{\"secure_url\":\"https://res.cloudinary.com/deh0vdgzd/image/upload/v1401318096/k6jrm2pehwycmehrkicz.png\",\"url\":\"http://res.cloudinary.com/deh0vdgzd/image/upload/v1401318096/k6jrm2pehwycmehrkicz.png\",\"resource_type\":\"image\",\"format\":\"png\",\"height\":960,\"width\":640,\"signature\":\"a8ca9bb867e0a3d99e1666b7891e8f918d81e627\",\"version\":1401318096,\"public_id\":\"k6jrm2pehwycmehrkicz\"}''}"'
```

Any idea why I don't get any response when I console.log it?

Comment: already tried to append .done(), .always(), and .fail() callback?

Comment: @Infer-On If jQuery is using Promises without being told to he has bigger problems.

Comment: I hope the actual server-response is not string-escaped? It needs to execute as code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out, the request I wrote was perfectly fine. The thing that was causing the the problem was response I was getting from server.

It was JSON stringified before return.

Answer (score 0):

With 'callback' in your querystring, JQuery wraps the response with a randomly generated method name. To get JSON (without method name), remove 'callback=?' from querystring.

If your server supports JSONP, you can make a call like this :

```
        $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
            },
            error: function(e) {
               console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps.